# An easier solution to re-establish a connection with MQTT in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mqtt

I'm developing an application that uses MQTT as middleware for communication between various connected devices.

What I'm trying to achieve is a notifier of sorts, that will notify all connected clients, when the broker is no longer available, and then, when the broker becomes available again.

For this, we're using `mqtt_client` which can subscribe to both connected and disconnected states, and, what we found is that, when the connection has been made once, the disconnection will trigger without fail, however, when we reconnect the broker, the connection state does not trigger again.

The `pongCallback` could be a solution, as we would need to call the *connect* function again to re-establish the connection with the broker on each of the connected devices, however, I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this?

The application will be used in an environment where the possibility of a power outage is real, and we need to be able to indicate to the users that a disconnect is in progress and notify them when the connection is re-established.

We briefly investigated the `pongCallback` available on the *MqttServerClient* object, however, we feel that this might cause a delay in re-establishing a connection with the broker.